# How modify java thread schedule to set real time schedule like FIFO?

Tags: java, pthreads, real-time, scheduler, thread-priority

I want to modify the schedule used by the running process in execution time to set a real time priority.

I would like to avoid use JNI wrapper to C functions.

For keep it simple, I want the similar function from POSIX thread on java.
    pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_FIFO, &sp);

Comment: Did you do any research on this topic?

Comment: Some, but i did not found to much information. Only with new thread, but not with a running thread.

Comment: Can you run system commands from your Java program? Are you on Linux? If so, you could try something like this, on the thread id of the desired thread in your process: 'chrt --fifo 99 <pid of thread>' The process that does it must have root privileges.

Comment: @ErikAlapää It's a good idea. thanks you. But I need a solution thats works on almost any unix system and windows.
chrt work on any UNIX system? and which will be the similar command on Windows?

Comment: You should be able to find something similar for other Unix OS:es as well, e.g. Solaris and *BSD. For Windows, things are a bit different, so there, I leave it for the Windows experts ;)